# Powershell: Get the number of logins for the past 90 days on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm trying to get the number of logins for the past 90 days on Windows servers.

But, I'm stuck in the very first step with:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-WinEvent -LogName Security| Where-Object {$_.ID -eq 4624}


   ProviderName: Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

TimeCreated                     Id LevelDisplayName Message
-----------                     -- ---------------- -------
4/5/2021 2:22:07 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:17:01 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:13:14 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:11:01 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:08:14 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:07:27 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:07:01 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 2:06:38 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:58:27 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:58:15 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:58:05 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:58:05 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:57:58 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:57:58 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:57:50 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:57:47 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:57:46 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:57:01 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:52:07 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:47:06 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:47:01 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
4/5/2021 1:45:16 PM           4624 Information      An account was successfully logged on....
```

because it's running forever like above and I don't get the prompt back.

I'm the only user on this Windows laptop and logged on only a few times today so far but it displays as if I've logged on for a few hundred times, taking more than 10 minutes just for today's logins.

So, I cannot go to the next step to parse the data, etc. to eventually count the number of logins.

Any tip would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Use built-in filter of `Get-WinEvent` instead of pulling complete log and do slow `Where-Object` filtering, e. g. `Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{ LogName='Security'; ID=4624; StartTime=(Get-Date).AddDays(-90) }`

Comment: @zett42 Thank you. Do you know why I'm getting those many login entries for each day? I log on at most a few times a day.

Comment: Various background processes also logon. You have to further filter the events to only get your own interactive logons. This question propably has already been answered before.

Comment: @zett42 Thank you for the pointer to the other thread. I tried one of the answers there, which seems to be the closest to what I'm trying to do: `Get-WinEvent -ProviderName 'Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing' -FilterXPath "*[System[EventID=4624] and EventData[Data[@Name='LogonType']='2']]" | select -First 100` but the output displays yesterday's sessions only (nothing for today's and nothing prior to yesterday's). Do you know why?

Comment: This command works for me. Try to include date/time range in the filter or use parameter `-MaxEvents 100` instead of `Select -First 100`.